# Apache CFX vs Spring MVC

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, cxf

For building a RESTful web service application that will consume and produce JSON is there any benefit to using Apache CFX over Spring MVC using and @RestController?

I've done some research on both and was planning on using Spring MVC and @RestController. However I've done some reading on Apache CFX and it is an implementation of both JAX-RS and JAX-WS. Apache CFX also claims to be high performance so I'm not sure how it would compare to Spring MVC with @RestController.

Is there going to be a significant difference between the two?

Comment: Is that a statement or a question?

Comment: I worded that poorly. I updated the question